# In Unity my gameObject is not affected by physics2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

in Unity 5.5, I'm trying to move a 2D gameObject via physics2D, but it remains unaffected. I'm a newbie, but I've already done an arkanoid clone, so moving an object shouldn't be a problem.

Moving by transform works, gravity, addForce, .velocity are not working. Or to be precise they are working, but not moving the object. Adding impulse changes the velocity of the rigidbody2D (adding force does not), but the position of my gameObject remains the same. I logged timeScale in the update function, so the game is not paused, and it's updating properly, the input is also working fine.

Relevant informations:

[image: GameObject and Project's physics2D properties]

[image: Script and runtime properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `Simulated` checkbox unchecked, that means the RigidBody2D is not simulated by the physics systems. The forces you are applying must be simulated on the body for them to take any affect.

Comment: Thank you mate, I had no idea what simulate means, I used v4.5 until now.